# How to access files present 2 steps above the root directory in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a root directory consisting of many folders and that sub folder has another folder and then csv file is present

[image: Root Folder ->Sub1 ->F1 ->File1.csv ->Sub2 ->F2 ->File2.csv]

I want to give the path of root directory. Go through each subfolder , take the csv as a dataframe and go to another folder, take that csv as dataframe and so on.  Can anyone please tell me how to do it?

Comment: You can use a `for loop` with `os.listdir` method to list the directories and then take files that you need from them.

Comment: or with Pathlib (using Root) and glob() function, or... you have many ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option itterrate through all subfolders until csv is found and append them to list

```
import pandas as pd
import os.path
import os

root_dir = "/dir/"
    
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(root_dir ):
    csv_list= []
    for filename in files:
        if filename.endswith('.csv'):
            csv_list.append(os.path.join(root, filename))
```

your csv_list will looks like this

```
print(csv_list)
```

Gives #

```
['fakepath/f1.csv', fakepath/f2.csv'...]
```

Itterrate over list and create a df.

```
import pandas as pd
df= (pd.read_csv(csv) for csv in csv_list)
final_df= pd.concat(df, ignore_index=True)
```